# Creating a simple script that disables unactive accounts

Tags: powershell

Trying to create a powershell script that will disable AD accounts after a certain amount of days. I want it to list out the SAMAccountName, DistinguishedName, and LastLogonDate, but when I add Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -confirm. The information no longer shows up and it goes straight into the confirm prompt. Wondering how i get it to display the information, and then give me the confirm prompt?

```
param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int] $daysInactive = 180
)

$stale = (Get-Date).AddDays(-($daysInactive))

Search-ADAccount –AccountInActive –DateTime $stale | Select-Object 
SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, LastLogonDate | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -confirm
```

Answer (score 0):

Split up your pipeline; Save the results of your search in a variable `$InactiveUsers`, then `write-host` that variable in a separate statement. Finally, pipe the variable to your `Set-ADUser` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Split the pipeline using the [`Tee-Object cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-6):

```
Search-ADAccount –AccountInActive –DateTime $stale |
    Tee-Object -Variable Users |
        Select-Object SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, LastLogonDate

$Users | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -confirm
```